# Linked In API returning 403 (Forbidden) when a request for email-address is made

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to get a user's email address from their Linked In.

I complete the whole OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow and get an access token but when I make a GET request to the endpoint `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(email-address)`, it returns a 403 (Forbidden) HTTP status code.

Here is what happens:

1. When I specify `r_liteprofile r_email-address` as the permission in the `scope` parameter when making a request for an authorization code, and when asking for data, as the `fields`, the parameter `projection=(localizedFirstName, localizedLastName, email-address)`, I get a 200 HTTP Status code but in the result JSON, I get only the `localizedFirstName` and `localizedLastName` values.
2. If I specify just the `r_emailaddress` permission in the `scope` parameter and `projection=(email-address)` when asking for data, I receive a 403 (Forbidden) Status Code.
3. If I specify just `r_emailaddress` in the `scope` field and leave out specifying any fields, i.e. I hit the `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` endpoint without any parameters (but the access token sent appropriately in the `Authorization` header as a `Bearer` scheme token), I get a 403 (Forbidden) HTTP Status Code.

My application does have permission for `r_emailaddress` as that is a basic permission that is granted to all applications upon creation and does not need approval.

[image]

Am I hitting the right endpoint for getting the email address? Everything seems to be alright but I still get a 403. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request to retrieve the email address is:

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))`

You need to request the r_emailaddress scope to use this endpoint.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context for reference.

Comment: I think I need your help with PUT https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:{developer application ID},user:urn:li:user:{member ID},entity:urn:li:organization:{organization ID},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)

We are adding everything as per in documentation but still it is giving a 403 error. 

Will you help please. This is on priority for me .

#linkedin